# How can I divide the values one by one in python?

Tags: python

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://olympics.com/tokyo-2020/olympic-games/ko/results/all-sports/medal-standings.htm'
res = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
data = soup.select('td.text-center')

for item in data:
    text = item.get_text().replace(' ', '')
    print(text)
```

[Result Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A616L.png)

I was crawling Tokyo Olympic medal standings, How can I change this like array(or list)?

Comment: What is the problem? Please develop better the question.

Comment: What values you want to divide and what do you want to change to array/list ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not good at English, I want to change the result of 'Result Picture' into a single line and change it to a list format.

Comment: @Ram Sorry for late mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text` to a `list` and print it.

Here I am adding the `text` to `res` list and printing it.

```
res = []
for item in data:
    text = item.get_text().strip().replace(' ', '')
    res.append(text)

# printing the res list
print(res)
```

Comment: How can I remove \r?

Comment: You can use ```strip()```. Updated the answer. Please check